# How to give a random style (top/left) to the const with queryselector?

Tags: javascript

I cant give a style with js to the starLoc Const
i get this error:
script.js:14 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'style')
at starMove (script.js:14:20)

```
const btn = document.getElementById('btn');
const star = document.querySelector('.space');
const starLoc = document.querySelectorAll('.star-obj');
var rndLeft = Math.floor(Math.random()*1000);
var rndTop = Math.floor(Math.random()*1000);
function startSpacing(){
    btn.style.display = 'none';
    starMove();
}
function starMove(){
    for(var i = 0; i <= 60; i++){
        star.innerHTML += '<div class="star-obj">*</div>';
        starLoc[i].style.left = rndLeft + 'px'; //14 line
        starLoc[i].style.top = rndTop + 'px'; 
    }
}
```

```
    <body>
        <div class="start">
            <button id="btn" onclick="startSpacing()">Start Space Moving</button>
        </div>
        <div class="space"></div>

        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </body>
```

what is wrong with const?

Do not judge strictly, I'm a beginner

Comment: Where did you place your script in the HTML?

Comment: @Unmitigated wait i will edit the post

Comment: When/how do you call `starMove()`? Does your JS run before the DOM has loaded? If so, those elements don't exist when you are attempting to access them.

Comment: @Unmitigated i placed js script in the bottom of html code

Comment: Your `star-obj` div isn't created untl you call `starMove()`, but you are trying to retrieve that element before you call the function . Move that line (`const starloc...`) inside your function.

Comment: @mykaf I changed the post

Comment: When do you call `startSpacing()`? My comment still applies. Youre accessing an element before it's created.

Comment: @mykaf I understand what you mean, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, in your HTML you call `startSpacing()` while the function name is `starMove()`. Second, you dynamically generate elements, so you need to get them every time the function is called. This means moving `starLoc` to the function. See the example with `color: red;`

```js
const star = document.querySelector('.space');
let rndLeft = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);
let rndTop = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);

function starMove() {
  for (let i = 0; i <= 60; i++) {
    star.innerHTML += '<div class="star-obj">*</div>';
    let starLoc = document.querySelectorAll('.star-obj');
    starLoc[i].style.color = 'red';
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="start">
  <button id="btn" onclick="starMove()">Start Space Moving</button>
</div>
<div class="space"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `document.getElementsByClassName` to get a live `HTMLCollection` of elements.

```js
const starLoc = document.getElementsByClassName('star-obj');
```

However, you should really use `document.createElement` in the loop instead.

```js
for (let i = 0; i <= 60; i++) {
    const div = document.createElement('div');
    div.textContent = '*';
    div.style.left = rndLeft + 'px';
    div.style.top = rndTop + 'px';
    star.append(div);
}
```